# Étymologie de « orthopédique »

Tags: étymologie, grec

> [[orthopedic (adj.) ]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orthopedic&allowed_in_frame=0) [<--] 1840, from French orthopédique, from orthopédie, coined by French physician Nicholas Andry (1658-1742), from Greek orthos "straight, correct" (see [ortho-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ortho-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***paideia*** "rearing of children," **from *pais* (genitive *paidos*) "child"** (see [pedo-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pedo-&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> [[TLF]](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/orthop%C3%A9die) Étymol. et Hist.
>   1741 «art de prévenir, de corriger les difformités du corps, surtout chez les enfants, à l'aide d'un appareil ou au moyen d'un traitement» (N. Andry de Bois-Regard, L'Orthopédie [titre]). [...]
>
> [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/132844?redirectedFrom=orthopedic#eid) [...] In some cases the element -paed- , -ped- appears to have been interpreted as deriving from classical Latin *ped-, pēs* foot (see [-ped comb. form](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/233829#eid13578443)).) [...]

D'après le TLF, voir ci-dessus, il semble que le docteur Andry avait l'intention d'adopter les morphèmes grecs, pour référer *seulement* aux maladies particulières des enfants plutôt qu'aux maladies désignées actuellement par ce nom (c-à-d celles d'os ou de muscles). Est-ce vrai ?

Alors, comment  ***paideia*** a-t-il evolué vers la définition contemporaine de orthopédie ? L'étymologie citée par l'OED semble une fausse interprétation de « pédie » dans « orthopédie ».

Comment interpréter cette étymologie pour comprendre comment les sauts sémantiques se sont écartés du sens littéral original ? Comment rapprocher les acceptions ultérieures des acceptions originales ?

Comment: You have already answered your question. The answer is in the extract of the OED you give. The confusion arose because of the proximity of  Latin *ped-*  with   *paideia* (rearing of a child).

Comment: Tu aurais devrais mettre ça en réponse et non en commentaire.

Comment: En vérité, les langues vivantes admettent plusieurs auteurs et donc plusieurs orthographes ; donc tous les sens et éthymologies sont acceptées.
il n'y a donc pas de sens littéral, saut sémantique ou mauvaises interprétations; il y aurait plutôt différentes écoles prônant chacune leur devenir sans oublier qu'une spécialisation tend à à créer ses propres définitions/vocabulaires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'après le petit Robert,

**1 -** dans le sens premier du nom :

- le 1e § de votre question est l’étymologie grecque du mot *orthopédie*, qui serait apparu en 1741, l'adjectif *orthopédique* (relatif à l'orthopédie) serait apparu en 1771.
- le 2e § est l'acception première du mot.

**2 -** dans le sens moderne de son utilisation (qui a de fait étendu au corps de l'adulte ce qui est déjà chez l'enfant : noter dans le 2e §  *surtout chez l'enfant*, car le squelette en formation pouvait être plus facilement corrigé) :

- Branche de la médecine qui étudie et traite les affections du squelette, des muscles et des tendons.

**3 -** dans un sens couramment accepté :

- le 3e § de votre question utilise l’étymologie latine (restrictive par rapport au **2 -**) : Orthopédie des membres inférieurs.

---

Ce n'est donc pas une étymologie unique linéaire, mais duelle et d'usage.